# Can set replicas in kubernetes deployment file as variabile?

Tags: kubernetes

I have my simple deployment.yaml file with pod configuration. The idea Is to use replicas Number as variable without using helm, how can I do?
There Is a way using the configmap variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have my simple deployment.yaml file with pod configuration. The idea Is to use replicas Number as variable without using helm, how can I do?

There is no native Kubernetes mechanism for setting the `replicas` value from a ConfigMap (or other resource). You would need to use some sort of templating mechanism, but it doesn't have to be Helm.

Assuming you wanted to deploy three replicas, you can use something as simple as `sed`, as in:

```bash
sed '/replicas:/ s/:.*/: 3/' deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f-
```

Or you can wrap your deployment in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: ${1:-1}
.
.
.
EOF
```

And then run:

```
sh create-deployment.sh 3 | kubectl apply -f-
```

etc.

You could use [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io) to patch the deployment with the desired value; your `kustomization.yaml` might look something like:

```
resources:
- deployment.yaml

patches:
- patch: |
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: example
    spec:
      replicas: 3
```

You would deploy that by running...

```
kubectl apply -k .
```

...in the same directory as your `kustomization.yaml` file.